# Trying to download with wget, but the authorization always failed

Tags: wget

I want to download files from a data server with username and password. I tried many times, but it always failed. Can you help me?

```
C:\ua-database>wget -r -np --tries=10 --user='<username>' --password='<password>' http:/
/ifp-08.ifp.uiuc.edu/protected/UASPEECH/
```

Results:

```
--2017-08-12 20:54:42--  http://ifp-08.ifp.uiuc.edu/protected/UASPEECH/
Resolving ifp-08.ifp.uiuc.edu... 130.126.122.224
Connecting to ifp-08.ifp.uiuc.edu|130.126.122.224|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required
Connecting to ifp-08.ifp.uiuc.edu|130.126.122.224|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required
Authorization failed.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272770/wget-with-authentication

Comment: @cbronson yes, thank you so much

Comment: @cbronson the page is not available at the present moment. Can you please provide the solution?